# Accessing environment variables securely client-side in Next.js (for FullCalendar)

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, fullcalendar, api-key

I am using FullCalendar in a Next.js project. I specifically am trying to feed it events from a public Google Calendar (see documentation [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar)). My problem is that linking FullCalendar to the Google Calendar API requires use of an API key, and I cannot figure out how to let the component access the API key *secretly*, since I cannot access .env.local variables client-side.

I know that, in general, you can make API routes that keep your API keys secret - but I'm not sure how/if that helps, since FullCalendar fetches from the Google Calendar API with its own logic.

I know you can also access API keys via the next.config.js, or in the .env.local if written with NEXT_PUBLIC_..., but if I understand correctly, then that will leave those keys exposed.

The following code correctly renders events from the public Google calendar:

```
<FullCalendar
        eventContent={(arg) => {
          return (
            <Tooltip title={arg.event.extendedProps.description} arrow>
              {renderInnerContent(arg)}
            </Tooltip>
          );
        }}
        headerToolbar={{
          start: "title",
          center: "dayGridMonth,listMonth",
          end: "today prev,next", 
        }}
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, list, googleCalendarPlugin]}
        initialView="listMonth"
        eventDisplay="block"
        weekends={false}
        googleCalendarApiKey="exposedApiKey" // sample API key
        eventSources={[
          {
            googleCalendarId:
              "sampleCalendar@group.calendar.google.com", // sample calendar address
          },
        ]}
/>
```

Thanks in advance.